# Github to Aws code deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

Can anybody please guide me how to easily deploy code from github to aws using aws cpde deploy ? I gave tried my best to deploy my code and it is not working as it gives error every time it launch deploy revision.

Comment: anyone can guide you, but, only if you can let SO users know what is the 'error' you getting, as you mentioned above? SO users can only help you, if you provide complete details of your problem.

Comment: Ravish sir i got no specific error deployment is just failing without error.

Comment: paste the error- and paste the command you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned deployment is failing. So I'm assuming github automatically kicking off the deployment part is working. Now for the deployment failure, do you see the instance being deployed marked failed? Can you also look into the instance and see if the codedeploy agent is running fine and paste the log here if possible?
-Surya